# Mapping string to int CPP - Output hangs during execution

Tags: c++, dictionary, syntax-error, runtime-error

I am currently doing a practice problem in hacker rank. The link is : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/linkedin-practice-dictionaries-and-maps

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


map<std::string, int> dict;
map<std::string, int>::iterator k;
int i, j, temp, n;
long long num;
//char check[100][100];
std::string str, sea;
int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    j = n;

    while(j--)
    {
        scanf("%s %d", &str, &num);
        dict.insert(make_pair(str, num));
    }

    printf("finished\n");
    printf("%s %d\n", "sam", dict["sam"]);
    while(scanf("%s", str))
    {
        if(str.empty())
            break;
        //printf("k is %s\n",str);
        k = dict.find(str);
        if(k != dict.end())
        {
            printf("%s %d\n", str, dict[str]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not found\n");
        }
    }

    getch();
}
```

The program runs fine until the printf statement "finished". Then in the next output for the dict statement occurs as

```
finished
sam 0
```

And in while statement, when it searches for string in map, the application hangs, and closes automatically. While inserting values I tried to use:

1. dict[str] = num;
2. dict.insert(pair(str, num));
3. dict.insert(make_pair(str, num));

Please mention if there is any corrections I need to do in the program. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement,

```
scanf("%s %d", &str, &num);
```

… is not a valid way to input a `std::string`. It has Undefined Behavior. All bets are off.

You can input to a `char` buffer, and conveniently `std::string` provides such a buffer. E.g.

```
str.resize( max_item_length );
scanf("%s %d", &str[0], &num);
str.resize( strlen( &str[0] ) );
```

Of course you can just use C++ iostreams instead, throughout the code, e.g.

```
cin >> str >> num;
```